# OneToMany targeting a list of abstract class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have this mapping:

Owner class

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Criteria {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID id;
    
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "criteria")
    private List<Condition> conditions;
}
```

Child (abstract) class

```
@Entity
@Inheritance
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type")
public abstract class Condition {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID id;
    
    @ManyToOne
    private Criteria criteria;
}
```

Inheriting classes

```
@Getter
@Setter
@DiscriminatorValue("A")
public class ConditionA extends Condition {
    // ...
}

@Getter
@Setter
@DiscriminatorValue("B")
public class ConditionB extends Condition {
    // ...
}

@Getter
@Setter
@DiscriminatorValue("C")
public class ConditionC extends Condition {
    // ...
}
```

When I build a `List<Condition>`, set it to a `Criteria` and try to persist it, I get this error:

> org.hibernate.InstantiationException: Cannot instantiate abstract class or interface:  : my.company.model.jpa.Condition

I have tried to type it as `List<? extends Condition>` but Hibernate simply won't start with this configuration, throwing another error.

How do I make this work?

Comment: You seem to be using Lombok - you might need to make sure all your classes except the abstract ones have default constructors JPA can access. Otherwise, this might be a bug in hibernate as what you've shown is correct from a JPA mapping perspective. I would guess that Hibernate has issues with lazy associations of abstract classes as it builds 'delegates'. Maybe show the exception stack trace, and see if it works when Condition isn't abstract - it shouldn't change anything functionally as long as you don't create Condition instances in the application.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you shouldn't be declaring Condition as an `abstract` class. Removing that will likely resolve your problem.

Since the default behavior of Hibernate Inheritance is keeping all values in the **same table**, the parent class needs to be able to instantiated as well in order for the table to be made (this is probably my best guess as to why it has to be instantiated; for initial data table creation).

You may also want to look at setting your Inheritance `strategy` which is of type InheritanceType as well.

Check out [this example here](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-inheritance).

Answer (score 0):

Your are annotating your `Condition` class with `Entity`, that's why Hibernate tries to persist it. If you don't want to persist objects of `Condition` you must annotate it with `MappedSuperclass` and remove the `Entity` annotation.